# Размещение Java Servlet на Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, jdbc

Сервлет использует JDBC. Чтобы сервлет работал jar файл c драйвером нужно положить в папку `WEB-INF/lib/`.
При запуске сервлета драйвер не подхватывается. Что я делаю не так?

UPD: Проблему решило явное создание объекта драйвера `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. Интересно, почему здесь это потребовалось. В обычном Java SE приложении работало и без явного создания.

Структура проекта
[image: структура]

Java Servlet:

```
package com.company.app.logic;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Item {

    private int itemId;
    private String itemName;

    public Item(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            this.itemId = rs.getInt(1);
            this.itemName = rs.getString(2);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return itemName;
    }
}


package com.company.app.logic;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    private static Main instance = new Main();
    private static Connection connection;
    private Main() {
       try {
           Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb";
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM items");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Item g = new Item(rs);
                items.add(g);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}


package com.company.app.web;

import com.company.app.logic.Item;
import com.company.app.logic.Main;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet("/items")
public class MainServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("text/html;charset=utf-8");

        PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();
        pw.println("<table border=1>");
        try {
            List<Item> l = Main.getInstance().getItems();
            for (Item item : l) {
                pw.println("<tr>");
                pw.println("<td>" + item.getItemId() + "</td>");
                pw.println("<td>" +item.getItemName() + "</td>");
                pw.println("</tr>");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServletException(e);
        }
        pw.println("</table>");
    }
}
```

Обычный Java SE проект:

```
package com.company.app.logic;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Item {

    private int itemId;
    private String itemName;

    public Item(ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            this.itemId = rs.getInt(1);
            this.itemName = rs.getString(2);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getItemName() {
        return itemName;
    }

    public int getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return itemName;
    }
}


package com.company.app.logic;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    private static Main instance = new Main();
    private static Connection connection;
    private Main() {
       try {

           String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/maindb";
           connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root");
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
    public static Main getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
    public List<Item> getItems() {
        List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM items");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Item g = new Item(rs);
                items.add(g);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (rs != null) {
                    rs.close();
                }
                if (statement != null) {
                    statement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = Main.getInstance();
        m.getItems().forEach(System.out::println) 
    }
}
```

Comment: Покажите код. В какой IDE работаете?

Comment: @Владимир, обновил вопрос, без IDE. `javac -d ../WEB-INF/classes/ -cp ".:../../../lib/servlet-api.jar" com/company/app/web/MainServlet.java`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Проблему решило явное создание объекта драйвера `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`. Интересно, почему здесь это потребовалось. В обычном Java SE приложении работало и без явного создания.

Это нормально. Если вы заглянете в код `DriverManager` (или почитаете спеку JDBC), то увидите, что он требует вызова статического метода `registerDriver()`. Очевидно, что для этого класс драйвера должен дернуть этот метод, и самое раннее место, где это можно сделать - блок статической инициализации класса (`static {...}`).

Статическая иницализация класса происходит при его загрузке classloader-ом. Обращение к классу по имени `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` как раз и заставляет classloader загрузить класс, а класс в свою очередь зарегистрироватья в `DriverManger`. До тех пор он спокойно лежит в CLASSPATH и никто о нем не знает.

---

Теперь понял, ваш вопрос можно перефразировать так: "Почему Tomcat не находит JDBC драйвер через service provider?".

В случае JavaSE приложения используется механизм загрузки через `ServiceLoader` из спецификации JDBC 4. При старте `CLASSPATH` сканируется на наличие файла(ов) `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver`, из которых `DriverManager` может получит имена классов, реализующих этот интерфейс и зарегистрирует их автоматически.

Проблема с Tomcat [описана на официальном сайте](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html) и связана с более сложной структурой загрузчиков и утечками памяти. Если кратко: Tomcat выполняет поиск драйверов через service provider только на своем старте, а не при деплое/старте каждого приложения. И доступны ему только jar-файлы в директории `$CATALINA_BASE/lib` (общие для всех веб-приложений). Для классов внутри вашего приложения из `WEB-INF/lib` эта возможность недоступна.

Кроме того, если вы используете способ с ручной регистрацией драйвера (`Class.forName`), настоятельно рекомендуется разрегистрировать драйвер при останове приложения, реализовав `ServletContextListener`.

Comment: Почему в обычном Java SE проекте работает без `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")` и `DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());`?

Comment: Я не вижу ваш "обычный JavaSE проект" .

Comment: изменил вопрос.

Comment: Вроде бы полсе появления JDBC 4.0 стало возможным не создавать явно объект драйвера.

Comment: @jisecayeyo, дополнил ответ